# How to allocate a static `SMatrix`/`SVector` using nalgebra?

Tags: rust, constants, builder, nalgebra

I would like to allocate an `SVector<f64, 7>` as a static variable. It seems that [nalgebra's library-provided builders cannot do this](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/latest/nalgebra/base/struct.Matrix.html#method.from_row_slice), as none of them are `const`. Is there a workaround?

Here's what I tried (this doesn't compile):

```rust
const C5: SVector<f64, 7> = SVector::<f64, 7>::from_row_slice(&[
  5179.0 / 57600.0,
  0.0,
  7571.0 / 16695.0,
  393.0 / 640.0,
  -92097.0 / 339200.0,
  187.0 / 2100.0,
  1.0 / 40.0,
]);
```

Edit: As @kmdreko pointed out, the following questions were more appropriate for a separate post:
[Why can't Rust use non-`const`-qualified functions to allocate `const` variables? Why does it matter whether or not a function is `const` if the data it's operating on is `const`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76895014/why-cant-rust-use-non-const-qualified-functions-to-allocate-const-variables)

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions but you should probably condense it to either focusing on the practical part with `SVector` or the theoretical parts. That would make your post more appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: The workaround is to do lazy initialization (not const initialization) with something like the lazy-static crate or its more in-style to use [`Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) from the once-cell crate.

Comment: Sorry for the barrage of questions! I'll see about making another post for the more theoretical ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a const constructor: [`from_array_storage`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/latest/nalgebra/base/struct.Matrix.html#method.from_array_storage).

```rs
use nalgebra::{ArrayStorage, SVector};

const C5: SVector<f64, 7> = SVector::<f64, 7>::from_array_storage(ArrayStorage([[
    5179.0 / 57600.0,
    0.0,
    7571.0 / 16695.0,
    393.0 / 640.0,
    -92097.0 / 339200.0,
    187.0 / 2100.0,
    1.0 / 40.0,
]]));
```

For your other questions:

- Rust has both [`const`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.const.html) and [`static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.static.html) values. If you need a global value that can't be constructed at compile time, then you can use a `static`, usually with something like [`Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) ([`LazyLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.LazyLock.html) in future Rust standard library), or [`thread_local`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.thread_local.html).
- Rust does not have the ability to promote a non-const function to const. If it could, then a change to the internals of a function could be a breaking change. However, Rust will evaluate `let` and `static` bindings at compile time if it is able and decides it is beneficial for optimization.
- Just because the parameters are const does not mean that all the operations inside a function are const. Usually this is allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly helpful answer! How does the "constructor" for `ArrayStorage` work? It almost makes sense, but I haven't seen anything like it in The Book... or perhaps it's a [tuple struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#using-tuple-structs-without-named-fields-to-create-different-types) with a single member? I'm also confused as to why there's two sets of square brackets.

Comment: Oops! [It is indeed a tuple struct, as indicated by this section that was staring me in the face](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/latest/nalgebra/base/struct.ArrayStorage.html#fields). It appears that the reason there are two sets of square brackets is that it stores the data in column-major order such that each array within the outer brackets contains a column of data.

Comment: Yeah, the double brackets was just to make this compile with the type you specified, which uses `ArrayStorage<f64, 7, 1>`. It could be that you wanted `ArrayStorage<f64, 1, 7>`, but that's no longer `SVector`.